# Problem with Chromium

Tags: chromium

I have a problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and Google Chromium, (details: Version 34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 14.04 aura (260972) ).
Chromium was working fine up to a recent install of updates from Ubuntu and now it won't open a browser at all, other than with a temporary profile when it seems to work OK.
I thought that Chromium had somehow got corrupted and uninstalled it, losing all my history and bookmarks in the process, and reinstalled thinking that the problem would be solved but to no avail.
Firefox on the other hand works just fine.
Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution?

Comment: what steps have you followed to install chromium

Comment: Hi agha rehan abbas, I tried uninstalling the original copy of Chromium, (which had stopped working), using the Ubuntu Software Centre. I have reinstalled the latest version of Chromium both through the Software Centre and Synaptic Package Manager neither of which has given me a working installation, other than with a temporary profile. Is there a Chromium equivalent of Firefox Clean Install which seems to get rid of all files from previous installations?

Comment: chromium has many bugs which are still to be fixed why dont you try out google chrome instead of chromium

Comment: Try uninstalling chromium completely with `sudo apt-get --purge remove chromium-browser` before installing it again. Also make sure your configuration in `~/.config/chromium` has been erased.

Answer (score 0):

you can download google chrome by running this command in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

or you can download it directly via software centre or try out this link to download it
[from here](https://www.google.com/intl/en_in/chrome/browser/)

Comment: The OP has a problem with Chromium. Installing another browser is not a solution, it is a way to escape the problem. He could also use Firefox, which works fine, and avoid installing anything else.